# How to make Directory in C Programming using File IO

Tags: c

I am a beginner C Programmer. I can make file (example .txt,.html etc) but now i try to make a directory in a specific location. But i can't success. Can any one help me to make directory with example ??

Comment: Varies a little by platform, but there's likely a `mkdir()` function you can use.

Comment: What platform are you using - Unix or Windows? Can you post some sample code that you've tried?

Comment: I am using windows. Friend i can find a solution from another friend named uditr043.

Answer (score 3):

For [linux](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mkdir)

```
mkdir("/some/directory", 0700);
```

For [Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fkk4dzw.aspx)

```
int main()
{
   system("mkdir C:\\Windows\\test");
}
```

I don't know what you mean by *FILE IO* but fopen doesn't create folder it just returns NULL if folder doesn't exists.

Comment: Using `system()` for simple filesystem operations is very bad idea.

Comment: friend myaut please tell a good idea for simple filesystem operation. and Advance thanks

Comment: @MdZobayer Rather than using `system()`, you should use the `_mkdir()` or `_wmkdir()` functions.  For some reason this answer links to the documentation for them, but uses `system()` instead in its example code.